# Swift main thread doesn't work

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm trying to update UILabel after get JSON data from server. I've tried many ways to fix it but it still doesn't work.

Here is my code

```
class ShopInformation: UIViewController {
var latitude = String();
var longitude = String();
var shopInformation:JSON = nil;

@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var addres: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/whatapro/json/shopinformation.php?latitude=\(self.latitude)&longitude=\(self.longitude)")

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
        (data, response, error) in
        //                print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        self.shopInformation = JSON(data: data!)
        print(self.shopInformation["response_data"][0])

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            self.name.text = self.shopInformation["response_date"][0]["name"].string
            self.addres.text = self.shopInformation["response_date"][0]["address"].string
        }

    }

    task.resume()
}
}
```

I also tried this way

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.name.text = self.shopInformation["response_date"][0]["name"].string
            self.addres.text = self.shopInformation["response_date"][0]["address"].string
        }
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Where and when are your labels initialised?

Comment: Another point including what @Wezly mentioned is if you have checked received values from the network request?

Comment: I updated the code. For the data I can retrieve it from server

Comment: You may want to describe how it isn't working and include any relevant error messages you're receiving.

Comment: There is no error. Just UILabel didn't update

Answer (score 1):

Expand your code to break out the values from your `JSON` into a separate variable. Set a breakpoint after you assign the variable, then examine the value in the debugger, and also examine the values of your `self.name` and `self.addres`outlets.

My guess is that one or both of your outlets is not connected.

(The first version of your code, using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())`, looks correct.)